# A problem about method of moments (MOM) and find the distribution of a event

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

> An urn contains $\theta$ black balls and $N-\theta$ white balls. A sample of $n$ balls is to be selected without replacement. Let $Y$ denote the number of black balls in the sample. Show that $(N/n)Y$ is the method-of-moments (MOM) estimators of $\theta$.

**My approach:** I know that:

> *Method of moment (MOM):* Choose as estimates values of the parameters that are solutions of the equations $\mu_{k}'=m_{k}'$, for $k=1,2,\ldots,t$ where $t$ is the number of parameters to be estimated and $\mu_{k}'=\mathbb{E}[Y^{k}]$ is the $k$-th moment of a random variable and $\displaystyle m_{k}'=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{k}$ is the corresponding $k$-th sample moment.

Now, 1) I need to know of the distribution of random variable $Y$, so I think that our *sole* observation  $Y$ is hypergeometric, but I don't sure about it. How can I check the first part?

2. I think here $t=1$, so we need to solve $\mu_{1}'=m_{1}'$. I think that part is easy if a can find the distribution for $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the Hypergeometric distribution,

$$\mu=\frac{\theta n}{N}$$

thus

$$\theta=\frac{N}{n}\mu$$

thus the MOM estimator of $\theta$ is

$$\hat{\theta}_{MM}=\frac{N}{n}\overline{Y}_n$$

because it has been obtained substituting the first moment with the first sample moment

Comment: So, is correct my approach:  $Y\sim \textbf{hypergeometric}(y,\theta,N-\theta,n)$ so,  we can see that $\mu_{1}'=\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{n}{N}\theta$ and $m_{1}'=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{1}=\overline{Y}$ and by MOM we need to find the solutions for $\mu_{1}'=m_{1}'$, in this case, it's sample because $$\frac{n}{N}\theta=\overline{Y} \implies  \theta=\frac{N}{n}\overline{Y}$$So, $\hat{\theta}=\frac{N}{n}Y$ is the estimator for $\theta$.?

Comment: Also, other estimator could be $\hat{\theta}=\frac{N}{n}\overline{Y}$?

Comment: Yes, this is the MOM estinator for $\theta$. See my edits in the answer

Comment: Thank you so much!